Get folder path instead of 'fakepath'
I need to place two text fields and two buttons. The first one uses a dialog to select the file name and place it in the textbox.
The second selects the folder with which the user will work and places it in the second textbox.
Or another option: after clicking on the first button, the file name is placed in the first textbox, and its path without a name is placed in the second.
The problem is that no matter how I write the code, it always displays C:/fakepath/
I tried to at least just display the path using this code and also got a fake pass:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="fileInput">File Input:</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <input type="text" id="inputTxt"><br><br>

    <button style="background-color: blue;" id="browseFile">Browse File</button><br><br>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#browseFile').click(function(){
                $('#fileInput').click();
            });

            $('#fileInput').change(function(){
                var filePath = $(this).val();
                $('#inputTxt').val(filePath);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Or how can I process this path, for example, on the server and return it back?

You can not get the user's path to the file due to security issues

You don't need the local path.  It means nothing once uploaded.   How you upload depends on your server and there will be 100's of tutorials / code samples to find only.  You can, of course, still ask here if you specify (in the question) the back-end.   Depending on what you want to do with the file, you may not need to uploaded and return, if for an image preview/edit it doesn't need a server-side file - you can read the content (in various ways depending on the need) within javascript.
